Massive redirect in nginx
I trying to configure massive redirect links like
https://example.com/products/Borbone-Crema-Classica-1-Kg_45668050

to
https://example.com/products/borbone-crema-classica-1-kg--45668050

via nginx and Perl.
First I need to change register of url from uppercase to lowercase:
Perl in nginx.conf
perl_modules perl/lib;
perl_set $uri_lowercase 'sub {
my $r = shift;
    my $uri = $r->uri;
    $uri = lc($uri);
    return $uri;
}';

Config in example.com.conf:
location /products/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase;
}

But the URL doesn't go to lowercase and links redirect me to main page

I've used this in the past to lowercase redirect URI's with NGiNX Perl:
perl 'sub { my $r = shift; $r->internal_redirect(lc($r->uri)); }';

So you'd just add it to your location:
location /products/ {
    perl 'sub { my $r = shift; $r->internal_redirect(lc($r->uri)); }';
}


I try your variant, but have no answer from server. Browser response is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
